# How to Suppress Typescript CSSProperties Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use the following code:

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button style={{WebkitAppearance: '-apple-pay-button'}}/>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Because there is no apple pay button currently defined in the CSSProperties type, I get a type incompatible error.

How can I suppress this error?

Comment: Thanks @AdamKosmala that worked for me. If you would suggest it as an answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that the fastest solution to this problem would be wrapping your component with styled components, or simply add css class to it and style it in your bundle css

Answer (score 0):

if the error come from typescript use

```
// @ts-ignore
```

if she come from tslint

```
/* tslint:disable */
<button style={{WebkitAppearance: '-apple-pay-button'}}/>
/* tslint:enable */
```

Comment: I already tried ts-ignore on the return statement. It did not work.
I can't put ts-ignore in the markup, so I'm not sure if I can use ts-ignore at all.

Comment: You can also rename your file extension to `.js`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button 
              /* @ts-ignore */
              style={{WebkitAppearance: '-apple-pay-button'}}
             />
        </div>
    );
}
```